# RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type HelloWorldWin was never called

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt

As I was following some code example on the internet. I bump into this code.

```
# minimal.py
from matplotlib.backends import qt_compat
use_pyside = qt_compat.QT_API == qt_compat.QT_API_PYSIDE
if use_pyside:
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
else:
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class HelloWorldWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kw):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = HelloWorldWin()

app.exec_()
```

for the line "QtGui.QMainWindow.**init**(self)" I decided to change the code to super(HelloWorldWin,self).**init**(self) for the sake of the convenience in the future. But This one gives me the following error

> RuntimeError: super-class **init**() of type HelloWorldWin was never called

Interestingly enough, when I take out self inside of bracket the error is gone.

I'm not sure why does it behave this way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you call a method with `super`, you're only supposed to pass `self` to `super`, not to the method.

Comment: @user2357112 I must have been using wrong way then. Thank you for the answer